# R: How to get the last element from each group?

Tags: r, aggregate, reduce, tail

I have a data frame containing a time series with two time stamp columns, `d$day` and `d$time`, and say, for simplicity, one measured variable `d$val1`.

Suppose I want to examine the situation at the close of each day's experiment, i.e. the last measurement, if it exists.  (Not every day has a measurement, and measurements can be taken at different times each day.)

I would like to be able to aggregate by `day` and use some sort of `last()` or `tail()` function on `time` to pull back the corresponding `val`.

I've tried variations like this with not much success (one issue is that tail requires an argument, but how to specify that within aggregate?)

```
 val_eod <- aggregate(d$val1, by=list(d$day), FUN=tail(...))
```

Any easier way to do this?

Comment: `FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)`? Or just `aggregate(val1 ~ day, d, tail, 1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
val_eod <- aggregate(d$val1, by = list(d$day), FUN = tail, n = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks - that variation works -- hadn't tried specifying the argument to tail as a comma'ed value next to tail