# Selecting the last observation in a group based on multiple columns

Tags: r, grouping

My data looks like the following:

```
CHAR1 CHAR2 CHAR3 CHAR4 CHAR5 DATE NUMERIC
```

The data are sorted in the correct order by CHAR1-5 and DATE (ascending). Numeric is the analysis value. How do I select the last observation by CHAR1-5 and DATE while retaining NUMERIC?

I tried a view options posted but they seem to require that NUMERIC be part of the assigned groups (which it is not). Other approaches use tables with single columns that also do not seem to work when expanded.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654219/get-first-and-last-values-per-group-dplyr-group-by-with-last-and-first ? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736229/r-how-to-get-the-last-element-from-each-group ?

Comment: Take a look at `tail()`.